# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown behaviour not clear

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

In my `Spring boot` application web container disabled. So when I start application it works and shutdown itself on complete. I did `@Async` method in service and run it from jUnit test. It works as it should in parallel threads. The problem with application shutdown though. When jUnit test done `Spring Boot` closes application but `@Async` threads still run in parallel and I got an exception. To make `@Async` threads able to done before shutdown i set **waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown** property to **true**. After that **Spring Boot closed but parallel threads not done and even no exception catched**. Why? How to force `Spring Boot` not close itself before parallel threads done?

Here app output with `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown = false`

```
Test thread closed
Thread sleep intrerrupted - async method test url string 2
Thread sleep intrerrupted - async method test url string 4
Thread sleep intrerrupted - async method test url string 0
Thread sleep intrerrupted - async method test url string 3
Thread sleep intrerrupted - async method test url string 1
```

Here app output with `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown = true`. As you see `@Async` method not output anything, so `@Async` threads are not done their job:

```
Test thread closed
```

---

**UPDATE** 
As proposed solution I tried to inject ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean in test, but result not changes. Same output as before. Here JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CLApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class CatalogPageServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    CatalogPageService catalogPageService;

    @Resource(name="locationPageExecutor")
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor locationPageExecutor;

    @Test
    public void processPageTest(){
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            catalogPageService.processPage(
                    new CatalogPage("test url string "+Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Test thread sleep intrerrupted");
        }

        locationPageExecutor.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Test thread closed");
    }
}
```

---

SpringBoot main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class CLApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CLApplication.class);

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor locationPageExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(20);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return executor;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Application main method call");
        try{
            SpringApplication.run(CLApplication.class, args);
        }catch(Throwable t){
            log.error("Unexpected error: ",t);
        }
        log.info("Application main method exit");
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CatalogPageServiceImpl implements CatalogPageService {

    @Override
    @Async("locationPageExecutor")
    public void processPage(CatalogPage catalogPage) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("print from Async method "+catalogPage.getUrl());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread sleep intrerrupted - async method "+catalogPage.getUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CLApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class CatalogPageServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    CatalogPageService catalogPageService;

    @Test
    public void processPageTest(){
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            catalogPageService.processPage(
                    new CatalogPage("test url string "+Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Test thread sleep intrerrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Test thread closed");
    }
}
```

Comment: JUnit exits as soon as `@Test` methods are all executed. It doesn't care about other daemon or non-daemon threads. If you want your test to wait until completion, inject the `ExecutorService`, shut it down, and await its termination. Similarly, refactor your `processPage` method to return a `Future` and block on `get` for each (all) invocation.

Comment: I just tried this but looks like nothing changes. Though not sure I did it right. I'll update my post now to show what I did.

Comment: Don't forget `setAwaitTerminationSeconds` and `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` on the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Comment: `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` already set to true. But with `setAwaitTerminationSeconds` I have doubts. I do not know how  @Async tasks will work, and I cannot break them before they done themselves.

Comment: Then use the `@Async` with `Future` return type solution. `Future#get` will block indefinitely.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this route. For test this looks reasonable. Should I use same approach in application to prevent exit before all tasks done?

Comment: I'd still rely on the termination of the executor for production. You can't wait forever to shutdown. After a while you have to stop.

Comment: The reason to not stop executor threads with timeout on production, because they later will work as consumer part of producer-consumer pattern and will be closed when get the last task with "exit" code from BlockingQueue. Now I just did sample @Async method to try how it will look like. The operation executor work with, itself, have timeout check, and strict exceptions handling, so it will not "hang" any way.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comnments. Looks like I got the point. TaskExecutor takes task Queue, so I not need to make my own. Now it works. And I have to force shutdown TaskExecutor, to exit application.